# Did Putin ever talk with Zelensky directly after Zelensky became president?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine

Putin in his recent interview with Tucker Carlson said that he talked with Zelensky about Zelensky's father, who, according to Putin, fought in WWII (it turned out that the father of Zelensky was actually born in 1947, so Putin probably referred to his grandfather).

But did they ever talk to each other at all either directly or via official communication channels?

Comment: Semen Ivanovych Zelenskyi (the grandfather) is a receipient of two Order of Red Star medal and following WWII, a police officer (some sort of leadership in USSR version of CSI). Oleksandr Semenovych Zelenskyi (the father) is a mathematician. So it is most likely the grandfather.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They met on 19th December 2019, on invitation by French President Macron, and together with German Chancellor Merkel in Paris (the so-called [Normandy format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normandy_Format)). An official statement about the meeting by Zelensky can be found [here](https://www.president.gov.ua/news/zagalni-uzgodzheni-visnovki-parizkogo-samitu-v-normandskomu-58797).

[image]

Answer (score 10):

> via official communication channels

They also talked by phone, on [July 11, 2019 for instance](https://warsawinstitute.org/phone-call-kremlin-putin-zelensky-10/). And possibly on other occasions.

> Putin and Zelensky talked about many issues: settlement of the conflict in Donbas, the release of captives and Ukrainian sailors detained by Russians, the future of the Normandy format. According to the Kremlin, the conversation was initiated by Ukraine.